# How do I use .NET DLLs outside GAC in PHP

Tags: php, .net, dll, .net-assembly, gac

I am a little bit confused about the fact that PHP can only use DLL files for a DOTNET object from the Global Assembly Cache and not from a local folder (from what I know). How is your site, that's using a DLL, going to work, when your web server doesn't have such a GAC? Right now I am developing on my local machine; No problem, but I am worried if I will be able to run my site elsewhere.

So my question is: Is it possible to access a DLL from another location than the GAC?

I have seen quite a lot questions/answers already, but all of them were relating to ASP.NET and how to use DLLs in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance
-Snrk

**EDIT:** I could describe what I want as a "LAC" (Local Assembly Cache).

Comment: Is this of any use: http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/calling-net-framework-and-net-assemblies-php ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that "my project" is just the location with my php files? And where do I put the code under "PREPARING THE NETPHP RUNTIME"?

Comment: I have added `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` and the code I was just talking about to a php file and run it; Doesn't work. Anyway it uses stuff from the GAC ... which is what I do not want.